# How do I hide the slack video pop up?

Tags: slack

While using slack's video chat if I focus on a different window a window pops up on my screen showing the same video chat. How do I disable the pop up window?

Comment: Slack is a web based app, and you just might get a quicker answer of quality if you searched in https://webapps.stackexchange.com . . And, OBTW, what did you find when you asked at https://slack.com/help/requests/new  ?

Comment: I just posted a question

Comment: it's not possible to hide it

Comment: Would you please be so kind as to make that an answer, including your source? TY

Answer (score 9):

I reached out to slack at slack.com/help/requests/new asking if it was possible to disable the small video window and this was their response:

> Thanks for getting in touch. I'm afraid it's not possible to turn off that video panel, the only way around it would be to put the app in focus in full screen mode.
>
> I'd be happy to share some feedback to our team that you'd like to be able to toggle off that video panel though! Let me know if you have any other questions.

So the answer is: no, it's not possible to hide the window.

Answer (score 4):

I have a workaround that works on Ubuntu + GNOME (I didn't test other distros but it could work).

1. While on a video/audio call on Slack, change the focus to other window or workspace other than Slack. The undesired popup window should appear.
2. Hover over the Slack icon on the Ubuntu Dock and click it. It must have three "windows" grouped together on Slack. The third window is the popup window (mini panel).
3. Click on the "X" to close the popup.
4. Profit!

[image: "X" button to close the Slack mini panel (popup)]

Now the annoying popup is gone, at least for this call. If you want it back, just leave the call and join it again.
Leaving the popup closed have no side-effects, you can still share your camera or your screen.

Comment: Similar - I use i3 and I do the window exit action and the call still continues.